# <div class="myclass"></div class="myclass">

Tags: html

Q1. Can I use `</div class="myclass">` in my HTML? It is working but not validated in w3c. As I experienced some difficult to find closed `<div>` and had to use `<!--myclass-->` to mark, and `<div class="myclass"></div class="myclass">` makes sense to me. 
Q2. Is validated HTML loading a little faster? As it isn't mentioned here.

Comment: here: http://validator.w3.org/docs/why.html#why_pros

Comment: Use the html comments to denote which div you are closing if you require clarity.

Comment: Purely technically, in HTML5 parsing-compliant browsers, valid HTML parses no faster than invalid HTML. In your case, the end tag will cause a `parse error' but browsers will not do anything different. The class attribute on the end tag is processed by the tokeniser and then discarded by the tree construction.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to specify which `<div>` you're closing - it has to be done in the same order they were opened. And that statement is valid to all HTML tags, not only `<div>`:

***correct:***

`<div><p>This is my <strong>first</strong> paragraph</p></div>`

`<strong><i>word</i></strong>`

***incorrect:***

`<div><p>This is my <strong>second</p> paragraph</div></strong>`

`<strong><i>word</strong></i>`

So, when you have multiple `<div>`s one in another they are always closed in given order:

```
<div> <!-- 1st -->
    <div> <!-- 2nd -->
        <p>My paragraph</p>
        <p>My another paragraph</p>
    </div> <!-- 2nd -->
    <div> <!-- 3rd -->
        <p>My paragraph</p>
        <p>My another paragraph</p>
    </div> <!-- 3rd -->
</div> <!-- 1st -->
```

And yes, you should assume, that valid HTML code will be better served to the end user by web browser. Valid HTML code should also be better and easier parsed by web crawlers used by search engines to index the WWW. That's why you should always try making it valid.